# how can i create run app even user close it android

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid

want create app cordova and ionic for android to alaram in some times like 2:50 and i want program run even close the program 
i use katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode plugin , but when i close program , it be close and dont still run in background this is code

```
  // Run when the device is ready
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

      // Android customization
      // To indicate that the app is executing tasks in background and being paused would disrupt the user.
      // The plug-in has to create a notification while in background - like a download progress bar.

      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
        title:  'TheTitleOfYourProcess',
        text:   'Executing background tasks.'
      });

      // Enable background mode
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

      // Called when background mode has been activated
      cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
        // Set an interval of 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds)
        setInterval(function () {
          var dd = new date();
          var h = dd.getHours();
          var m = dd.getMinutes();
          if(h == 2 && m ==50){
            alert("2:50");
          }
        }, 3000);
      }
    }, false);
```

how can i make app still run even user close the program like , alarm clock or some program reminder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

this might be helpful